# Monerod rpc method getblock - blob data

Tags: monerod, monerod-commands

https://getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html

Using the monerod json rpc, we can get the blob data for a specific block.

`curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:18081/json_rpc -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"getblock","params":{"height":912345}}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'`

blob data returned for that block:

`"blob": "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",`

block hash for that block:

`"hash": "e22cf75f39ae720e8b71b3d120a5ac03f0db50bba6379e2850975b4859190bc6"`

I think the blob is made up of the blockheader, nonce, Merkle root hash and size of transactions.

Using get_block_longhash from https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/960886aa04f0b50265884c0d4338031a93b1bc5d/src/cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_format_utils.cpp#L883

Can we hash that blob manually, which should yield its block hash?

Also what's the difference between the *getblock* method **blob** and the *getblocktemplate* method **blocktemplate_blob** ?

Answer (score 2):

The block header or block isn't what is being hashed.

The block header contains versions, timestamp, coinbase tx, and other ancillary info.

The block contains the header, as well as a list of transaction IDs.

The block hashing blob, which is different contains the block header plus the number of transactions and the Merkle tree root (ie, not the whole set of tx ids). That is what is being hashed for PoW.

`getblocktemplate` gets you the block hashing block in the `blockhashing_blob` field.

Comment: actually iam trying to generate `blockhashing_blob` 's for old blocks. how to extract merkel tree hash for old blocks?

Comment: I am able to build blockhashing_blob for old blocks with version, nonce, prev hash,size of txs but couldn't generate merkle hash.

Comment: See tree_hash in src/crypto. Recursive hashing of a tree of those hashes.